# Rails & nested comments through partials, strange recursion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I've got a pretty simple setting for (polymorphic) comments model which also have a has_many relationship wih itself (called :replies):

```
# comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :asc) }
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment_parent, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: "comment_id"
  has_many :replies, class_name: "Comment", foreign_key: "comment_id"
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :commentable, presence: true
end
```

In the post controller I fetch the comments:

```
@comments = @commentable.comments.all()
```

I'm initiating the partial on my blog view page like so:

```
= render @comments
```

And finally the comment/_comment partial containing:

(simpiflied code, this only shows gravatar & username)

```
# comment/_comment.html.haml
%ol.media-list
  %li.media{:class => ("media-replied" if comment.comment_id)}
    = link_to gravatar_for(comment.user, size: 80, class_name: 'media-object img-circle'), comment.user, class: 'pull-left'
    = render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: comment.replies
```

Somehow this creates some strange recurrence, in which replies get shown on their correct location, but also on an incorrect location. Problem is that there doesn't seem to be any logic in this. (at least for me it doesn't)

I've checked console to verify that the database contains the correct relations between the records (no faulty records), so it must be in the presentation / partial call.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was my own stupid mistake of course... the call @commentable.comments.all() result is all the comments, so even the nested comments are shown as if they are top level.

Short term fixed it by adding where(comment_id: nil)